# How to export color scheme from Rider?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, webstorm, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm trying to export Visual Studio Dark color scheme by clicking export button in dropdown menu to the right of the scheme name, then I get a file, which looks like this:

`<scheme name="Visual Studio Dark copy" version="142" parent_scheme="Visual Studio Dark"> <option name="FONT_SCALE" value="1.0" /> <metaInfo> <property name="created">2017-11-14T17:52:25</property> <property name="ide">Rider</property> <property name="ideVersion">2017.2.1.0.0</property> <property name="modified">2017-11-14T17:52:34</property> <property name="originalScheme">_@user_Visual Studio Dark</property> </metaInfo> <option name="EDITOR_FONT_SIZE" value="12" /> <option name="EDITOR_FONT_NAME" value="Menlo" /> </scheme>`

Why this file looks like this? I do the same things with WebStorm and I get a file full of xml code which I can successfully import in any IDE by JetBrains.

Comment: You are exporting your copy (`name="Visual Studio Dark copy"`) which has little to no modifications as compared to parent scheme -- it has only difference to parent. Try exporting parent instead.

Comment: I tried to export parent too, doesn't work, can it be a Rider's bug? Because I export schemes from webstorm/phpstorm without any problems

Comment: Should be the same -- it's a platform-wide functionality. Not a Rider user so cannot verify .. but in  PhpStorm 2017.2.x it exports bundled scheme just fine (in full); my custom (that is based on one of the bundled) is exported similar to yours -- only my changes. So -- try exporting ALL bundled schemes instead (one by one). ALSO -- please post a screenshot of how the scheme selector looks like (I want to see a list of schemes and how they are shown)

Comment: in webstorm I can't export default and darcula too, hmm, but can export all other schemes, like monokai etc. You mean this [link](https://prnt.sc/hh0buy) ?

Comment: Yes. So what .. all of them on export produce small files?

Comment: Yep, I tried everything, it's not really known problem, googling doesn't help, so I'll leave this problem opened, what if some1 will be able to export this scheme, I hope this person will let me know XD

Comment: File a ticket then -- it's better than just sit and wait for a possible miracle: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RIDER

Answer (score 5):

Parent color scheme files are not exportable by default. You can export them by going into the Rider installation folder, then `/lib`. Copy the `rider.jar` file and rename it `rider.zip`. Inside the zip, you'll have a `colorSchemes` folder, with all the Rider and Visual Studio color schemes. You'll need to change their extension to `.icls` to be able to import them.

The color schemes are unfortunately not entirely compatible with IntelliJ IDEA and probably other IntellIJ Platform IDEs. I tried it, and the granularity in the color scheme settings is not the same as Rider, so the inheritance is broken.

Comment: This actually worked just fine for me, including inheritance. (Rider C# to CLion Rust)